# Binary Tree Paths at Leetcode, code doesn't satisfy a test case?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, depth-first-search

I'm new to data structures and algorithms and I'm trying to solve this specific [Leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-paths/) and I am currently stuck at a test scenario where the input is: `[1,2,3,null,null,4]`

My code output is `["1->2","1->4"]` and the expected output is `["1->2","1->3->4"]`

My code is below (I know it's not the most efficient as I'm still trying to wrap my head around BFS and DFS), it would be great if someone can point out where I'm going wrong?

```
 /**public class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode() {}
 *     TreeNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
 *     TreeNode(int val, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
 *         this.val = val;
 *         this.left = left;
 *         this.right = right;
 *     }
 * }
 **/
class Solution {
public List<String> binaryTreePaths(TreeNode root) {
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        String result = "";
        String first = Integer.toString(root.val);
        Stack<TreeNode> stack = new Stack<>();
        TreeNode current = root;
        stack.push(root);
        while(!stack.isEmpty()) {
            
            if(stack.size()==1) {
                result = first;
            }
            current = stack.pop();
            if(current.val!=1) {
                result+="->"+Integer.toString(current.val);
            }
            if(current.left==null && current.right==null) {
                results.add(result);
                continue;
            }
            else {
                if(current.right!=null) {                    
                    stack.push(current.right);
                }
                if(current.left!=null) {
                    stack.push(current.left);
                }
            }
        }
        return results;
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include `TreeNode` and `main` with hard coded test data to make your code [mre]. We should be able to copy-pate-run. We also need to know what is the expected output.

Comment: Ah yes sorry have edited and added the TreeNode class, I will work on adding an executable main method thank you